# What is the optimal number of public/private subnets for the AWS FLASK/React/MySQL application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, subnet

I am thinking that I should create 3 public subnets and 3 private subnets, one pair for GUI React, one pair  for Flask, one pair for MySQL. Is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subnet is bound to an availability zone. If you're planning on having application become highly available you should have a public/private subnet per availability zone of your region.

This helps to provide mitigation for your application against availability zone failure, however you would still need to setup the architecture to support this such as autoscaling groups for applications and having a multi az setup for your database.

You would either have one public subnet (per AZ) for all traffic or one per role (per AZ), that part is entirely upto you. You should only have public subnets for public facing applications.

If this is a personal project then you're free to reduce the infrastructure sizing as per what is appropriate for your project.

More information on best practices available [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/vpc/architecture.html).